# Display flex is messing around with my items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container that has a list of items, each item has an image and some information.

I made a slide function using JavaScript and I got into a little problem, because I'm using `translateX`, I want the items to be displayed inline.

I made some research and found that I must use `display: flex` when making a sliding image, and after that, the items are not showing correctly.

If I **remove** the `flex` and I put `translateY` (instead of `X`) the slide is working (from up/down) but I want from left-right.

Can someone help me?

This is the code that is not work (with `display: flex` and `translateX`)

```js
var count = 1;

var next = document.querySelector('button.next');

var items = document.querySelectorAll('div.item');
var size = items[0].clientWidth;

next.addEventListener("click", function(e)
{
    if(count == 2) {
        return;
    }

    count++;

    document.querySelector('div.main').style.transition = 'transform 1.0s ease-in-out';
    document.querySelector('div.main').style.transform = 'translateX(' + ((-size * count)) + 'px)';
});

var prev = document.querySelector('button.prev');

prev.addEventListener("click", function(e)
{
    if(count == 1) {
        return;
    }

    count--;

    document.querySelector('div.main').style.transition = 'transform 1.0s ease-in-out';
    document.querySelector('div.main').style.transform = 'translateX(' + ((-size * count)) + 'px)';
});
```

```css
.content {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.container-slide {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 600px;
    max-height: 600px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    float: left;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 70%;
    color: white;
    background: green;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.buttons-info {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

button.prev, button.next {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.show-list-pages {
     position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="container container-slide">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://i.redd.it/7nk7p8gl90371.jpg')">
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="buttons-info">
                            <div class="show-main-text">
                                <span>title item 2</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="buttons-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <button><span>button 1</span></button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="show-list-pages">
                        <div class="show-current-page">
                            <span>1</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="show-count-pages">
                            <span>/ 2</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://assets.hongkiat.com/uploads/minimalist-dekstop-wallpapers/4k/original/14.jpg')">
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="buttons-info">
                            <div class="show-main-text">
                                <span>title item 1</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="buttons-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <button><span>button 1</span></button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="show-list-pages">
                        <div class="show-current-page">
                            <span>1</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="show-count-pages">
                            <span>/ 2</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="prev">prev</button>
<button class="next">next</button>
```

This is the other code without `display: flex` and `translateX` (is working) but the next item is not showing (because is not on inline, is under the first item)

```js
var count = 1;

var next = document.querySelector('button.next');

var items = document.querySelectorAll('div.item');
var size = items[0].clientWidth;

next.addEventListener("click", function(e)
{
    if(count == 2) {
        return;
    }

    count++;

    document.querySelector('div.main').style.transition = 'transform 1.0s ease-in-out';
    document.querySelector('div.main').style.transform = 'translateX(' + ((-size * count)) + 'px)';
});

var prev = document.querySelector('button.prev');

prev.addEventListener("click", function(e)
{
    if(count == 1) {
        return;
    }

    count--;

    document.querySelector('div.main').style.transition = 'transform 1.0s ease-in-out';
    document.querySelector('div.main').style.transform = 'translateX(' + ((-size * count)) + 'px)';
});
```

```css
.content {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}

.main {
  /*display: flex;*/
  width: 100%;
}

.container-slide {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 600px;
    max-height: 600px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    float: left;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 70%;
    color: white;
    background: green;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.buttons-info {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

button.prev, button.next {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.show-list-pages {
     position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="container container-slide">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://i.redd.it/7nk7p8gl90371.jpg')">
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="buttons-info">
                            <div class="show-main-text">
                                <span>title item 2</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="buttons-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <button><span>button 1</span></button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="show-list-pages">
                        <div class="show-current-page">
                            <span>1</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="show-count-pages">
                            <span>/ 2</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://assets.hongkiat.com/uploads/minimalist-dekstop-wallpapers/4k/original/14.jpg')">
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="buttons-info">
                            <div class="show-main-text">
                                <span>title item 1</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="buttons-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <button><span>button 1</span></button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="show-list-pages">
                        <div class="show-current-page">
                            <span>1</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="show-count-pages">
                            <span>/ 2</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="prev">prev</button>
<button class="next">next</button>
```

This is the code without `display: flex` and `translateY` instead of `X`, is working from up-down, but I want from left-right

```js
var count = 1;

var next = document.querySelector('button.next');

var items = document.querySelectorAll('div.item');
var size = items[0].clientWidth;

next.addEventListener("click", function(e)
{
    if(count == 2) {
        return;
    }

    count++;

    document.querySelector('div.main').style.transition = 'transform 1.0s ease-in-out';
    document.querySelector('div.main').style.transform = 'translateY(' + ((-size * count)) + 'px)';
});

var prev = document.querySelector('button.prev');

prev.addEventListener("click", function(e)
{
    if(count == 1) {
        return;
    }

    count--;

    document.querySelector('div.main').style.transition = 'transform 1.0s ease-in-out';
    document.querySelector('div.main').style.transform = 'translateY(' + ((-size * count)) + 'px)';
});
```

```css
.content {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}

.main {
  /*display: flex;*/
  width: 100%;
}

.container-slide {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 600px;
    max-height: 600px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    float: left;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 70%;
    color: white;
    background: green;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.buttons-info {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

button.prev, button.next {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.show-list-pages {
     position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="container container-slide">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://i.redd.it/7nk7p8gl90371.jpg')">
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="buttons-info">
                            <div class="show-main-text">
                                <span>title item 2</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="buttons-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <button><span>button 1</span></button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="show-list-pages">
                        <div class="show-current-page">
                            <span>1</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="show-count-pages">
                            <span>/ 2</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://assets.hongkiat.com/uploads/minimalist-dekstop-wallpapers/4k/original/14.jpg')">
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="buttons-info">
                            <div class="show-main-text">
                                <span>title item 1</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="buttons-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <button><span>button 1</span></button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="show-list-pages">
                        <div class="show-current-page">
                            <span>1</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="show-count-pages">
                            <span>/ 2</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="prev">prev</button>
<button class="next">next</button>
```

**EDIT:** I solved this issues, I just added `min-width: 100%` to the `.item`.

Comment: Not directly related, but you have two event listeners for the next btn and none for the prev btn. Probably wont solve the issue at hand tho.

Comment: I edited, it wasn't because of that, the problem is still persisting...

Comment: none of your events is working in the code snippet. please review your code.

Comment: please add .info class in your CSS. define width of info class.

Comment: @ækit done, i've made some changes and added more examples. It was already added the .info to my css with a specific width.

Comment: do want to do something like [carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a carousel.
this is what I changed in CSS.

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  width: 200%;
}
.item{
  width:100%;
}
```

this is what I changed in JS.

```
//in next -50% it shifts half way through .main
 document.querySelector('div.main').style.transform = 'translateX(-50%)';
// in prev 0% it goes back to start
 document.querySelector('div.main').style.transform = 'translateX(0%)';
```

```js
var count = 1;

var next = document.querySelector('button.next');

var items = document.querySelectorAll('div.item');
var size = items[0].clientWidth;

next.addEventListener("click", function(e)
{
    if(count == 2) {
        return;
    }

    count++;

    document.querySelector('div.main').style.transition = 'transform 1.0s ease-in-out';
    document.querySelector('div.main').style.transform = 'translateX(-50%)';
});

var prev = document.querySelector('button.prev');

prev.addEventListener("click", function(e)
{
    if(count == 1) {
        return;
    }

    count--;

    document.querySelector('div.main').style.transition = 'transform 1.0s ease-in-out';
    document.querySelector('div.main').style.transform ='translateX(-0%)';
});
```

```css
.content {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  width: 200%;
}

.container-slide {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 600px;
    max-height: 600px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    float: left;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
}

.info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    background: green;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.item{
  width:100%;
}
.buttons-info {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

button.prev, button.next {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.show-list-pages {
     position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="container container-slide">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://i.redd.it/7nk7p8gl90371.jpg')">
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="buttons-info">
                            <div class="show-main-text">
                                <span>title item 2</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="buttons-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <button><span>button 1</span></button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="show-list-pages">
                        <div class="show-current-page">
                            <span>1</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="show-count-pages">
                            <span>/ 2</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://assets.hongkiat.com/uploads/minimalist-dekstop-wallpapers/4k/original/14.jpg')">
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="buttons-info">
                            <div class="show-main-text">
                                <span>title item 1</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="buttons-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <button><span>button 1</span></button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="show-list-pages">
                        <div class="show-current-page">
                            <span>2</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="show-count-pages">
                            <span>/ 2</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="prev">prev</button>
<button class="next">next</button>
```

this is not the optimal solution as I tried to keep that original code.
this won't work if you add more than 2 images.

Comment: Yes, this is, but I want to show just only 1 item with only 1 image, not both images (items) when i click next/prev.

Comment: oops, I forgot to check js for full screen.

Comment: Yes, but if I have more items with images, for example 3 or 4 or 5, it doesn't go to the next item (image) correctly.

Comment: ok if you don't want to keep your code I can give you the proper carousel.

Comment: I still want to keep my code..

Answer (score 0):

I created a variable translateAmount that starts at 0 and tracks where the carousel is at, and then it translates by the current amount. That way you can always translate it the right amount, your count variable keeps track of the number of pictures.

I also put a width 100% on the .item and width 200% on the .main div. I needed this because with the display: flex it tends to put everything in the screen.

Take a look:

HTML/JS

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="container container-slide">
          <div class="main">
            
              <div class="item">
                <div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://i.redd.it/7nk7p8gl90371.jpg')">
                  <div class="info">
                      <div class="buttons-info">
                          <div class="show-main-text">
                              <span>title item 2</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="buttons-item">
                        <a href="#">
                            <button><span>button 1</span></button>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="show-list-pages">
                      <div class="show-current-page">
                          <span>1</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="show-count-pages">
                          <span>/ 2</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
              <div class="item">
                <div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://i.redd.it/7nk7p8gl90371.jpg')">
                  <div class="info">
                      <div class="buttons-info">
                          <div class="show-main-text">
                              <span>title item 2</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="buttons-item">
                        <a href="#">
                            <button><span>button 1</span></button>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="show-list-pages">
                      <div class="show-current-page">
                          <span>1</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="show-count-pages">
                          <span>/ 2</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
              <div class="item">
                  <div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://assets.hongkiat.com/uploads/minimalist-dekstop-wallpapers/4k/original/14.jpg')">
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="buttons-info">
                            <div class="show-main-text">
                                <span>title item 1</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="buttons-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <button><span>button 1</span></button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="show-list-pages">
                        <div class="show-current-page">
                            <span>1</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="show-count-pages">
                            <span>/ 2</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <button class="prev">prev</button>
    <button class="next">next</button>
    
    <script>
      var count = 1;

      var next = document.querySelector('button.next');

      var items = document.querySelectorAll('div.item');
      var size = items[0].clientWidth;
      
      let translateAmount = 0;

      next.addEventListener("click", function(e)
        {
          if(count == 3) {
            return;
        }

        count++;

        translateAmount -= size;
        document.querySelector('div.main').style.transition = 'transform 1.0s ease-in-out';
        document.querySelector('div.main').style.transform = 'translateX(' + translateAmount + 'px)';
      });

      var prev = document.querySelector('button.prev');

      prev.addEventListener("click", function(e)
      {
        if(count == 1) {
            return;
        }

        count--;

        translateAmount += size;
        document.querySelector('div.main').style.transition = 'transform 1.0s ease-in-out';
        document.querySelector('div.main').style.transform = 'translateX(' + translateAmount + 'px)';
      });
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.content {
  /* margin-left: 50px; */
  border: 0px solid red;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
}

.item {
  width: 100vw;
}

.container-slide {
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 50%; */
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    /* position: relative; */
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 600px;
    max-height: 600px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    /* float: left; */
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 70%;
    color: white;
    background: green;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.buttons-info {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

button.prev, button.next {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.show-list-pages {
     position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: That works, but if you have like 5 items of 5 images each, it doesn't show correctly. (multiply .item and you will see)

Comment: Right. Enclose the items inside the .content div and put overflow:hidden, so you can put width: 100vw in the .item (then it will take up 100% of the .content div). I edited my answer, check now, please.

Also, right now the count check is being done manually, you will have to change it every time you add an image. Maybe you could add images dynamically, and store them in an array. That way the maxCount could be set to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to change the entire code then here is the solution.

source MEDIUM [carousel from scratch in vanilla JS](https://medium.com/@marcusmichaels/how-to-build-a-carousel-from-scratch-in-vanilla-js-9a096d3b98c9)

codepen.io [carousel](https://codepen.io/ankitcodes/pen/OJxyvKv)

```js
!(function(d){
  var itemClassName = "carousel__photo";
    items = d.getElementsByClassName(itemClassName),
    totalItems = items.length,
    slide = 0,
    moving = true;
  
  
  // Set classes
function setInitialClasses() {
  // Targets the previous, current, and next items
  // This assumes there are at least three items.
  items[totalItems - 1].classList.add("prev");
  items[0].classList.add("active");
  items[1].classList.add("next");
}
// Set event listeners
function setEventListeners() {
  var next = d.getElementsByClassName('carousel__button--next')[0],
      prev = d.getElementsByClassName('carousel__button--prev')[0];
  next.addEventListener('click', moveNext);
  prev.addEventListener('click', movePrev);
}
  
  
  // Next navigation handler
function moveNext() {
  // Check if moving
  if (!moving) {
    // If it's the last slide, reset to 0, else +1
    if (slide === (totalItems - 1)) {
      slide = 0;
    } else {
      slide++;
    }
    // Move carousel to updated slide
    moveCarouselTo(slide);
  }
}
// Previous navigation handler
function movePrev() {
  // Check if moving
  if (!moving) {
    // If it's the first slide, set as the last slide, else -1
    if (slide === 0) {
      slide = (totalItems - 1);
    } else {
      slide--;
    }
          
    // Move carousel to updated slide
    moveCarouselTo(slide);
  }
}
  
  function disableInteraction() {
  // Set 'moving' to true for the same duration as our transition.
  // (0.5s = 500ms)
  
  moving = true;
  // setTimeout runs its function once after the given time
  setTimeout(function(){
    moving = false
  }, 500);
}
  
  
  function moveCarouselTo(slide) {
  // Check if carousel is moving, if not, allow interaction
  if(!moving) {
    // temporarily disable interactivity
    disableInteraction();
    // Update the "old" adjacent slides with "new" ones
    var newPrevious = slide - 1,
        newNext = slide + 1,
        oldPrevious = slide - 2,
        oldNext = slide + 2;
    // Test if carousel has more than three items
    if ((totalItems - 1) > 3) {
      // Checks and updates if the new slides are out of bounds
      if (newPrevious <= 0) {
        oldPrevious = (totalItems - 1);
      } else if (newNext >= (totalItems - 1)){
        oldNext = 0;
      }
      // Checks and updates if slide is at the beginning/end
      if (slide === 0) {
        newPrevious = (totalItems - 1);
        oldPrevious = (totalItems - 2);
        oldNext = (slide + 1);
      } else if (slide === (totalItems -1)) {
        newPrevious = (slide - 1);
        newNext = 0;
        oldNext = 1;
      }
      // Now we've worked out where we are and where we're going, 
      // by adding/removing classes we'll trigger the transitions.
      // Reset old next/prev elements to default classes
      items[oldPrevious].className = itemClassName;
      items[oldNext].className = itemClassName;
      // Add new classes
      items[newPrevious].className = itemClassName + " prev";
      items[slide].className = itemClassName + " active";
      items[newNext].className = itemClassName + " next";
    }
  }
}
  
  
  function initCarousel() {
  setInitialClasses();
  setEventListeners();
  // Set moving to false so that the carousel becomes interactive
  moving = false;
}
  
  
  initCarousel();
}(document));
```

```css
.carousel-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-wrapper * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.carousel {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.carousel__photo {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
  height:60vw;
  max-height:90vh;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: transform .5s, opacity .5s, z-index .5s;
}

.carousel__photo.initial,
.carousel__photo.active {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 900;
}

.carousel__photo.prev,
.carousel__photo.next {
  z-index: 800;
}
.carousel__photo.prev {
  transform: translateX(-100%); /* Move 'prev' item to the left */
}
.carousel__photo.next {
  transform: translateX(100%); /* Move 'next' item to the right */
}

/* buttons */
.carousel__button--prev,
.carousel__button--next {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: #FFF;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer; 
  z-index: 1001; /* Sit on top of everything */
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.carousel__button--prev {
  left:0;
}
.carousel__button--next {
  right:0;
}
.carousel__button--prev::after,
.carousel__button--next::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 54%;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(135deg);
}
.carousel__button--next::after {
  left: 47%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-wrapper">
  <div class="carousel">
    <img class="carousel__photo initial" src="https://i.imgur.com/sKV54PO.jpeg">
    <img class="carousel__photo" src="https://i.imgur.com/dZH9gh8.jpeg">
    <img class="carousel__photo" src="https://i.imgur.com/TBgEy0n.jpeg">
    <img class="carousel__photo" src="https://i.imgur.com/1PeQdB4.jpeg">
    <img class="carousel__photo" src="https://i.imgur.com/ox8Cp47.jpeg">
      
    <div class="carousel__button--next"></div>
    <div class="carousel__button--prev"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but i really want to keep my code.